# How To convert URL link into UIImage in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I am Using UIImage View and add Image there like this code

```
 NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://d1mxp0yvealdwc.cloudfront.net/e92c939d-e83b-4592-b367-327fa67339fb/1001 123.jpg"];
NSLog(@"imge %@",imageURL);

NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    NSLog(@"imge %@",imageData);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
   NSLog(@"imge %@",image);
[image_view setImage:image];
```

but all of nslog show null Actually there is problem in url but this show image on web so please tell me what's the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL string has a space which needs to be replaced with percent escapes.

Either use this -

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://d1mxp0yvealdwc.cloudfront.net/e92c939d-e83b-4592-b367-327fa67339fb/1001%20123.jpg"];
```

Or

```
NSString *imageUrlString = @"http://d1mxp0yvealdwc.cloudfront.net/e92c939d-e83b-4592-b367-327fa67339fb/1001 123.jpg";
NSString *encodedImageUrlString = [imageUrlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString: encodedImageUrlString];
```

Comment: If you think this is a duplicate then you should be marking as a duplicate not just saying it is in your answer. I have removed this comment.

Answer (score 5):

Try Following Code :

```
NSURL *aURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://d1mxp0yvealdwc.cloudfront.net/e92c939d-e83b-4592-b367-327fa67339fb/1001%20123.jpg" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

UIImage *aImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:aURL]];
```

This is working fine...!!!